# Node.js "res is not defined"

Tags: javascript, node.js

What Javascript do I add to define res?  Thanks!

Error message:

> ReferenceError: res is not defined

Code:

```
app.get('/', function(request, response) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/public', 'index.html'));
})
```

Comment: res === response in this instance.

Comment: @WalkerRandolphSmith  Thanks!  Do you know what Javascript I add to define it?

Comment: @Lanie909 just change `res.sendFile` to `response.sendFile`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are calling the `sendFile` method of `res` but you are not declaring `res`, you are declaring `response`, see below. It is also standard to pass in req/res as shorthand.

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/public', 'index.html'));
})
```